# Unable to istall angular9....!!! visual studio ask for git login?

Tags: angular, git, angular9

First I have installed angular11 and successfully start working on my project, but then I need to install angular9 in order to start working. Thus I have uninstalled it, and again try to install angular 9  by using the command: npm install -g angular/cli @9.0.3 ............. but this time it ask for git login, I have given but still not be able to install angular anymore every time shows error.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDo20.png)

My node version is v12.16.3
npm version is 6.14.4.............. I am very new in angular, please help.

Comment: It should be `@angular/cli@<version>`. But why use such an old version of the cli?

Comment: @fredrik someone told me that angular11 is not a stable version, as I was unable to do  ngif else on my previous project

Comment: If you are learning Angular - stability hardly matters that much.

Comment: I will keep your advice in mind while learning Fredrik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm install -g @angular/cli@wished.version.here
```